# Embed live video stream in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, video-streaming, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook to control a lab environment and would like to be able to view a live camera stream embedded in the web browser. The notebook server is accessed both from the local machine and remotely. The current implementation

```
%pylab notebook

def get_frame(): #Dummy
    return randint(0,255,(1544, 2064))

fig = figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=120)
img = imshow(get_frame())

def test_update():
    for i in range(20):
        img.set_data(get_frame())
        fig.canvas.draw()

test_update()
```

gives a pretty poor performance in frames per second (max. 2fps). As image processing is also done in the notebook an inline solution would be ideal.

What is a possible solution to get higher frame rates?